# ContextMenuOpening event not trigered

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a button with a context menu, but I just can get the ContextMenuOpening event to triger.

```
<Button Name="a_button"
        ContextMenu="{StaticResource MyContextMenu}"
        ContextMenuOpening="MyContextMenu_Opening" >
</Button>

private void MyContextMenu_Opening(object sender, ContextMenuEventArgs e)
{
   // doesnt get here.
}
```

Any ideas how to make this work ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just checked your code and it works perfectly.

Here is my full xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ContextMenu x:Key="MyContextMenu">
            <MenuItem Header="Send" />
        </ContextMenu>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Button Name="a_button"
                ContextMenu="{StaticResource MyContextMenu}"
            ContextMenuOpening="MyContextMenu_Opening" >
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And *.cs:

```
    private void MyContextMenu_Opening(object sender, ContextMenuEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Comment: Very strange, cannot understand why it is not working, its look perfectly fine.

Comment: You need to search some another problem.

Answer (score 2):

ContextMenuOpening event must be handled on an ancestor of the ContextMenu not on the ContextMenu itself. If you try handling it on the ContextMenu the event only fires when you right click once ContextMenu is already open.